# Who exactly is this Rebel Trooper?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-clone-wars, return-of-the-jedi, retcon

In the *Return of the Jedi*, there is a rebel trooper who has a small amount of screen time and has a *fine* white beard.

[image: rebel trooper in question]

Now I have heard speculation this is trooper is supposed to be Captain Rex from the *Clone Wars* show. Rex in his old age also sports a *fine* white beard.

[image: Old Rex]

Now obviously the trooper from *ROTJ* was not originally supposed to be Rex as *Clone Wars* is a much newer show. However, has there been any confirmation that a retcon has been made, or is it just a fan theory? If there is a retcon, is it a canon one, or just something that the showrunners liked?

Comment: Alas, now the Valorum updated his answer on the duplicate target, this is indeed a duplicate.